# best alternative to QuickTime .mov

Tags: codec, quicktime, avid

My company is stripping away QuickTime enterprise-wide, due to Apple dropping support for the format.  I use After Effects and Premiere, and others in my group are on Avid Workstations.  Occasionally when I create a video, I'm handed .mov files exported from Avid Media Composer and Sorensen Squeeze to work with in Adobe software, usually as QuickTime uncompressed.  Now that we are unable to work with QuickTime, going forward, what's the best codec alternative to import clean footage to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple is dropping support for the player, so no new releases, but the format remains and can be decoded by recent versions of CC without needing Quicktime to be installed. See

http://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/quicktime-on-windows/

> Adobe has worked extensively on removing dependencies on QuickTime in
>   its professional video, audio and digital imaging applications and
>   native decoding of many .mov formats is available today (including
>   uncompressed, DV, IMX, MPEG2, XDCAM, h264, JPEG, DNxHD, DNxHR, AVCI
>   and Cineform). Native export support is also possible for DV and
>   Cineform in .mov wrappers.

http://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/apple-quicktime-on-windows-update/

> Today we’re pleased to announce that Adobe has been able to accelerate
>   work that was already in progress to support native reading of ProRes.
>   This new capability is fully licensed and certified by Apple, and
>   barring any unforeseen issues during pre-release, these fixes will be
>   included into an update to the relevant products in Creative Cloud
>   shortly.

Comment: You may want to clarify the difference between the [QuickTime File Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFPreface/qtffPreface.html) (the container) and the [QuickTime Player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime) since this is bound to be a FAQ in the near future.